# How to get results where column 1=1 and column 1=2?

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

How to get results where column 1=1 and column 1=2? 
let's say I have three tables and need the following output:

Employee table

```
eid      name
1        john
2        jack
3        matt
```

Service table

```
sid service
1   shipping
2   delivering
3   storing
4   accounting
```

Employee_Service table

```
esid eid sid  
1    1   1
2    1   2
3    1   3
4    2   1
5    2   4
6    3   1
7    3   3
8    3   4
```

This code is not working when I write "and" in where clause instead of "or"

```
SELECT e.[eID],
       e.name,
       s.sid
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
     LEFT JOIN dbo.employee_service es ON e.eid = es.eid
     LEFT JOIN dbo.service s ON es.sid = s.sid
WHERE s.service = 'shipping'
  AND s.service = 'storing';
```

Result should be like this

```
eid  name  sid 
1    john  1    
1    join  3   
3    matt  1    
3    matt  3
```

going forward, I'd like to have results like this:

```
eid   name   sid   sid
1     john   1      3
3     matt   1      3
```

Thank you!

Comment: `s.service` cannot be 'shipping' and 'storing' at the same time.  Your query will, of course, return nothing all the time, because both conditions can't be satisfied all the time.  Why would you want `and` instead of `or`??

Answer (score 0):

To get into format like

```
eid   name   sid   sid
1     john   1      3
3     matt   1      3
```

you should *conditional* aggregation like

```
SELECT e.[eID],
       e.name,
       shipping= MAX(CASE WHEN s.service='shipping' THEN s.sid END),
       storing= MAX(CASE WHEN s.service='storing' THEN s.sid END)
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
     JOIN dbo.employee_service es ON e.eid = es.eid
      JOIN dbo.service s ON es.sid = s.sid
WHERE s.service in( 'shipping', 'storing')
GROUP BY  e.[eID],e.name HAVING COUNT(1)=2;
```

<kbd>**[See this demo](http://rextester.com/QNKZK16291)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use OR instead of AND. The same column can't get two different values in a row.

And I would use INNER JOINS instead of LEFT JOIN, if you don't want to get empty column results, if one of the values doesn't exist in another table.

And it's always better to filter by using the Id

so "where s.sid = 1 or s.sid = 3" or easier "where s.sid in (1,3)"

This should work:

```
SELECT e.[eID],
       e.name,
       s.sid
FROM [dbo].[Employee] e
     INNER JOIN dbo.employee_service es ON e.eid = es.eid
     INNER JOIN dbo.service s ON es.sid = s.sid
WHERE s.sid in (1,3)
```

Comment: This won't work.  This will also pick up eid 2, which is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
e.eid
,e.name
,s_sid
FROM dbo.employee e
INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT es.eid, s.sid,
    s_sid = STUFF(
                  (
                   SELECT ' ' + CONVERT(char(1), s.sid)
                   FROM  dbo.employee_service e_s 
                   INNER JOIN dbo.service s ON e_s.sid = s.sid
                   WHERE es.eid = e_s.eid 
                   AND s.sid IN(1, 3) -- change sid to change the service
                   FOR XML PATH(''))
            , 1, 1, '')
 FROM dbo.employee_service es 
 INNER JOIN dbo.service s ON es.sid = s.sid
) t ON e.eid = t.eid
WHERE s_sid = '1 3' -- change this according to the sid you chose previously
```

Instead of having a different column for each service, "sid"s are stuffed in a row and separated by a space (thanks to STUFF function).
Then if you change the parameters of the clauses I commented, you can get any result you desire according to sid number.
Hope this is helpful!

Comment: This code sounds amazing! However, I receive an error msg:
Must declare the table variable "@employee".

Must declare the table variable "@employee_service".

Comment: My tables have a @ in front of them, I will remove them right now so that it refers to your tables

Comment: Now it should work! Remember to vote the comment up so that everyone can use the query if they wish :)